# C++ compiler - Microsoft Surface Pro X running ARM SQ2 chip

Tags: c++, compilation

I've recently bought a surface pro x for general (social) use, and was wondering if there is a C++ IDE that I can use for the occasional bit of development work... The key issue from my investigations is that the surface pro x uses an ARM chip, which is not compatible with Visual Studio for compiling. I understand there is Visual Studio Code which is a kind of emulator(?), but is seems you can't actually compile with it (if I've understood correctly). Maybe I'm mistaken though, so would appreciate an opinion from someone more informed than myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any Windows on ARM device to test but I found some one tested then post result here: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11iK3z_jXv0wdSCuJ1oFKGb0z9j__CzvZ7tMMH73xbG8/edit#gid=85435074&range=D182) (Latest update may be in 2020, result can be different from 2021)

> Visual Studio 2019 works on Surface Pro X, but it's not complete. This works at a slow speed. It also consumes much more memory than on x86 machines.
>
> - Build C / C ++ x86 code. Executable. Debuggable.
> - Build C / C ++ x64 code. Can't execute. Can't debug.
> - Build C / C ++ ARM64 code. Executable. Not debuggable (Debugger of VS2019 only allows remote debugging if ARM target)
>
> In the case of ARM64, you can write and build code in Visual Studio 2019. And you can debug using WINDBG (ARM64). But It's a lot of inconvenience.

Conclusion: Just build x86, this is fine.